:hover на mouse, а :active на tach
В Css возможно разделить, для курсора применяем hover, а при касании active?

для :hover - @media (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) будет применяться для мыши
для :active - @media (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) будет применяться при наведении пальца на сенсорном экране
pointer: fine используется для указателей, которые обладают высокой точностью, как мышь
pointer: coarse указывает на указатели с низкой точностью, такие как палец например


.my-button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #007BFF;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}


/* Стили для устройств с указателем мыши */

@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {
  .my-button:hover {
    background-color: red;
  }
}


/* Стили для сенсорных устройств */

@media (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) {
  .my-button:active {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
<button class="my-button">для курсора применяем hover(красный), а при касании active(желтый)</button>



